# Flag - displays incorrect flag reason

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flagging

After I flagged [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7480/uses-for-leftover-potatoes-from-a-pot-roast) as being "too broad", I went to check its status and clicked flag again. It shows me that I raised 2 flags on it, one for `it should be closed for another reason...` and one for `it is a duplicate...`. Both these options are also disabled and so I cannot raise the flags again for these reasons.

This seems to be a bug as I didn't raise a flag for it being a duplicate but only one for it to be closed for being too broad. Can this be fixed please?

EDIT: [Another question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8818/how-can-i-use-up-leftover-dips) with the same issue. I'm starting to believe that it happens with all questions flagged this way.

[image]

Comment: This happens on all SE sites. I think the idea is that you can't change the "normal" close reasons but you can elevate it to a more serious flag. For example someone may post an off-topic question and later you notice (or they edit in) spam or something offensive. At 3k rep you can retract a close vote, but you still can't change it to something else either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this makes sense, even if it's not the most clear language: it's saying that you raised that *type* of flag (a close-vote-ish flag) already, not that specific one. It's not telling mods you raised both of those flags, don't worry.

And you can't vote to close a question for two different reasons, so it's pretty consistent that you also can't flag it for multiple close vote reasons. If you really need to convey extra information you can use a custom flag. For example if you didn't realize it was a dup, and now you do, it could be helpful to tell us what question it's a duplicate of.